# Elasticsearch Creating an Analyzer and Adding Stop Words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filter, elasticsearch, analyzer

I would like to create an analyzer and add a few stop words to Elasticsearch. I am having trouble finding documentation on doing so.

Every tutorial I find (including on the elasticsearch website) simply says to configure the analyzer...

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": { 
          "type": "standard", 
          "stopwords": [ "and", "the" ] 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... but I don't know how to actually get to the analyzer and pass in my own stop words, filters, etc.

If you could help me out, or point me in the direction of some in depth documentation that would be awesome.

Comment: And where are you stuck, because it's not clear to me? The stopwords are defined in the analyzer itself (`"stopwords": [ "and", "the" ] `) and the analyzer is used like this `"some_text_field": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }`.

Comment: I would like to add more words to the list. Do I access the analyzer through the terminal? The analyzer above is just an example I found.. not the one I am using.

Comment: Add more words on the fly? You can't. Once you define the analyzer, that's it. If you want to change it, back up the index, delete the index, then change the mapping by creating a new index, re-index your data. More about this here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime